# QGIS attribute table not dissolving records

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dissolve

So I have a filtered shapefile layer with only 2 records:

[image]

I use dissolve tool, selecting all fields, since I have tried different combinations

[image]

Yet, final attribute table of dissolved image still shows same number of records, when I expect only one register

[image]

I have tried different ways to do it, but it always returns same number of previous records. There must be something wrong the way I do it, since in many tutorials no problem like this is shown (they usually dissolve based only on one field, which I have tried, no good results at all), what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) (emphasis mine):

> **Dissolve**
>
> Takes a vector layer and combines its features into new features. One
> or more attributes can be specified to dissolve features belonging to
> the same class (***having the same value for the specified attributes***)

So don't try to dissolve using fields with different values, unless you don't want those records merged.

It looks like (but I can't be sure as some fields are larger than shown in your screenshots) TIPO_TRANS, RUTA_CORRE, DETALLE and DESCRIP contain the same values for both records, so dissolve on those fields, *not* on ID or DETALLE_2 as those fields have different values.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked really well! I never saw those details, in documentation.